# Присвоение значение переменной

Tags: python

Всем привет! У меня возникла такая проблема. Мне нужно присвоить значение переменной одной функции переменной другой функции. Интерфейс к этому модулю я сделала в Qt design. Вывод для графика использовала виджет MatPlotLib. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне можно из функции `file_open` присвоить значение переменной `orig_log` переменной `original_log` в функции `file_begin`.

```
class StartQT(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_mplinterfeis):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_mplinterfeis()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.mplbutton_open, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                               self.file_open) #   при нажати кнопки mplbutton_open запускается функция file_open

    def file_open(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        myfile1 = open(filename.getOpenFileName()) # открываю нужный мне график
        orig_log = np.loadtxt(myfile1, usecols=[0, 1])
        orig_log = Programms.Log('orig_log', orig_log[:,0], orig_log[:,1])#функция LOG определяет столбцы значений ( по Х и по Y)
        self.ui.mpl.axes.plot(orig_log.values, orig_log.depths)# вывод графика
        self.ui.mpl.axes.get_xaxis().grid(True)
        self.ui.mpl.axes.get_yaxis().grid(True)#прорисовка осей графика
        self.ui.mpl.draw()

    def file_begin(self):
        top_defined = 2777
        bottom_defined = 2800
        original_log = ?
       (top_target, bottom_target) = Programms.result_function(original_log,
                                                            target_log, 
                                                            top_defined,
                                                            bottom_defined,
                                                            wavelet_level,
                                                            limit_of_stretching,
                                                            variant_for_functional,
                                                            number_of_solutions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое тут  - использовать глобальные переменные.

Comment: а глобальные переменные использовать в самом классе или вне класса. Я просто не понимаю как их использовать, тем более у меня все функции находятся в одном классе

Comment: А, вот теперь поправили и вижу, что это методы одного класса.

Тогда все еще проще. Делаете эту переменной свойством класса.
Например, в одной функции инициируете эту переменную

    self.aa='AAA'

А в другой используете ее значение

    print (self.aa)

Comment: спасибо большое за совет

Answer (score 0):

Используй self. Только так можно добиться этого.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]